# Using Symfony2 as a dynamic View proxy

Tags: caching, symfony

Here is my situation:

I am using Symfony2 as a **middle layer** here, when web client ask for a webpage to Symfony2(the layer), the layer is going to request single/multiple data/image to **another backend remote resource server by http**, combine them and return to web client.

And I also wish to have **caching** in order to reduce requests to the backend server.
I found that the ESI has similar manner, however, could I include another server resource in Symfony2?

Is there any proper way to implement this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether you have Varnish installed in front of Symfony2 or not. 
To be clear: Symfony2 ESI Proxy won't call any external resources, and will only call your app's controllers.

Varnish is able to handle the ESI from any sources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on Varnish, let me go to take a look on that.